# Cannot Resolve method ' addOnClickListener'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[SnapShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPDzF.png) Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompletionListener(com.myAppliction.signup, anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompletionListener)

I'm trying to add User in firebase but this Error keeps Coming.

```
Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
user.put("Username", username);
user.put("Password", password);
user.put("email", email);
db.collection("users").add(user).addOnCompleteListener(signup.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("signUpSuccessful", "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException )task.getException();
                        Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Failed Registration: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;                    
                        }

                    // ...
                 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you are adding a complete listener of type `AuthResult` instead of `DocumentReference`. The listener that you have added is used when you authenticate the user and **not** when you add it to the database. So the following code will to the trick:

```
db.collection("users").add(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            //User successfully added
            Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Failed Registration: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move it inside View's onCreateView. This error occurs when you write it anonymous class.
Please put the image link in the correct place and if possible share code of signup.java because there is no problem inside addOncompletelistner